# Is there a regular method to solve some types of integro-differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations, integro-differential-equations

So I just got out of my first exam on differential equations. One point had an integral equation which we were supposed to turn into a first order linear differential equation. The thing is I wasn't able to get rid of the integral and ended with an integro differential equation that looks like this:

$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{1}{nx}f-\frac{1}{nx^2}\int_{0}^{x}f(k)dk ;~ n\in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm not sure if I made any mistakes, but that's not the point. How could I solve an equation like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{df}{dx}=\dfrac{f}{nx}-\frac{1}{nx^2}\int_{0}^{x}f(k)dk ;~ n\in \mathbb{R}$$
Note that:
$$nx^2\frac {df}{dx}=xf-\int_0^xf(k)dk$$
$$n\frac {df}{dx}=\left ( \dfrac {\int_0^xf(k)dk}x \right )'$$
Integrate both sides.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Before I had that integro differential equation I had that. You just made realize I overcomplicated the problem ._. . Thanks!

Comment: Although, my main question hasn't been answer. What's the regular method? Just trying to convert it into a differential equation?

Comment: As Player said in the answer. You can alwaus differentiate to get a differential equation that you can solve @Shadow3456TB

Comment: Your equation is just a first order differential equation @Shadow3456TB

Answer (score 0):

Turn the equation into
$$nx^2\frac {df}{dx}=xf-\int_0^xf(k)dk$$

and differentiate (using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus):

$$nx^2\frac {d^2f}{dx^2}+2nx\frac{df}{dx}=f+x\frac {df}{dx}-f=x\frac{df}{dx}$$

Then simplify, and let $g(x)=\dfrac {df}{dx}$:

$$\frac {dg}{dx}=\frac {1-2n}{nx}g$$

which is a first-order ODE, with solution:

$$g(x)=c_1x^{\frac1n-2}\implies f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac {c_1n}{1-n}x^{\frac1n-1}+c_2&\text{for }n\ne 1\\c_1\ln x + c_2&\text{for }n=1\end{cases}$$